# Oracle SQL - How to group by a column and count other column for each different value?

Tags: oracle, group-by, plsql, count

I'm struggling trying to get the desired result when querying 2 tables.
These are the tables:

## Table1

| column1 (fk) | column2 | other_columns... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | a |  |
| 2 | a |  |
| 3 | c |  |
| 4 | a |  |
| 4 | b |  |
| 4 | b |  |
| 4 | d |  |

## Table2

| column1 (pk) | column2 | other_columns... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01 |  |
| 2 | 02 |  |
| 3 | 03 |  |
| 4 | 04 |  |
| (more ids) | more... |  |

What I'm trying to accomplish here is creating a view for grouping by **table2-column2** and counting the occurrence of **a**, **b**, **c** and **d** (every different data in **table1-column2**) for every row of the grouped column; something like this:

## Desired view

| table2-column2 (grouped-by) | a (count) | b (count) | c (count) | d (count) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 02 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 03 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 04 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| more... | count... | ... |  |  |

There is a **one2many** relation between the tables: **table1** can have multiple entries with the same foreign key; so **table1-column2** can have multiple duplicated entries for the same data in the column, as shown. All different values in **table1-column2** are known values, so *where* clauses can be used.

I'm having a hard time trying to count the occurrences of every different data in **table1-column2** for a specific entry in the grouped-by column (I'm getting the whole amount of entries in **table1** for every type of data in **table2-column2**).

I also tried to create *selects* for every type of known data in **table2-column2**, but I didn't know how to return only one row in that situation, so error **single-row subquery returns more than one row** was triggered.

Any suggestion is very well appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Cold you please give us your tables as DDL (text) and your data as DML (also text) - ideally as a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk)? Help us to help you!

Comment: Hi. Thank you for welcoming me and for trying to help. I was actually creating the fiddle you asked me for when @Justin Cave replied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want something like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f4c757a4c8c60a0375866e46da35b571)

```
with t1 as (
  select 2 c1, 'a' c2 from dual union all
  select 2, 'a' from dual union all
  select 3, 'c' from dual union all
  select 4, 'a' from dual union all
  select 4, 'b' from dual union all
  select 4, 'b' from dual union all
  select 4, 'd' from dual
),
t2 as (
  select 1 c1, '01' c2 from dual union all
  select 2, '02' from dual union all
  select 3, '03' from dual union all
  select 4, '04' from dual)
select t2.c2,
       sum( case when t1.c2 = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) count_a,
       sum( case when t1.c2 = 'b' then 1 else 0 end) count_b,
       sum( case when t1.c2 = 'c' then 1 else 0 end) count_c,
       sum( case when t1.c2 = 'd' then 1 else 0 end) count_d
  from t2
       left outer join t1 on (t1.c1 = t2.c2)
 group by t2.c2
 order by t2.c2
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you!